# Can someone explain these Definitions about Cell Complexes for me?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

I've been reading "On a small cancellation theorem of Gromov" by Yann Ollivier (https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.36045%2Fbbms%2F1148059334 ) recently and these definitions aren't really clear for me since the author never really described what he meant by combinatorial 2-complex. I am also not really sure what he means when talking about faces and multiplicity of faces.
Maybe someone has already read this article and give me a hint about what is meant or even draw a picture for me.
Thanks!

[image: Definition 4]

[image: Definition 5]

Comment: Well I don't see how a $2$-comlex - which usually suggests you sto at dimension $2$ - can have arbitrary $D_{n+1}$

Comment: This is probably a modification of the standard notion of a CW 2-dimensional complex, where cells are defined not as maps of disks but maps of punctured disks.

Comment: Indeed, in Definition 4 of the paper, $D_{n+1}$ is "an open disk \dots with $n \geq 0$ holes."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay thanks I had the right idea then.